# Why does less directives/more html take longer to compile than more directives/less html?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In our app, we have several layers of nested directives. In an attempt to speed up the digest cycle, we removed some top level directives that have data-bindings to static data. Instead, we just generated the html from the static data, and compiled that. However, after doing that, we started getting unresponsive script warnings in Firefox. The compile time on this generated html was taking too long.

I'm hoping to gain a better understanding of the compile process in these 2 different scenarios so that we can optimize correctly in the future. [Here is a very simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnc253/uhJY9/) that shows the problem. Here is the important part of it:

```
var repeaterHtml = '<div repeater="allData"></div>';
var staticHtml = '';
angular.forEach($scope.allData, function(currData, currIndex) {
    staticHtml += '<div dir1="allData[' + currIndex + ']"></div>';
});
$element.append(staticHtml);
```

When using the `staticHtml` it takes significantly longer to compile than when just using the `repeater` directive. Why is this? Is it purely because there is more html to go through? As angular compiles the `repeater` directive does it not have to do the same compiling as I was doing manually? When the final DOM is exactly the same, what is it about the `repeater` directive that makes it compile so much faster?

I'd appreciate any insight into this. Thanks.

Comment: Updated your fiddle with better debugging options: http://jsfiddle.net/uhJY9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** - your `repeater` directive does nothing special - it is just a wrapper for `ng-repeat`. To understand why `repeater` is faster than manipulating the `DOM` from the controller, you need to understand how `ng-repeat` works, what are `compilation` and `linking` phases.  AFAIR Miško Hevery - has a talk about this here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho

There are few things you are doing in your example that cause it to be slower than angular `ng-repeat`

1. Manipulating `DOM` in `controller` - **don't do that**! This practice is very bad! The reason `ng-repeat` is faster in this case is because it compiles the `DOM` once and only produces copies of the repeated element for each element in the array. In your case, you are creating element from string after the `DOM` has been rendered, then you modify the `DOM` structure by appending the element to the `document`, and after that, you are compiling the element you have just created against scope, which again modifies the `document's` `DOM`! You only need to compile the element once, and the append it to the parent (but do it in a directive - not in controller).
2. If you want to have a faster implementation of `ng-repeat` (but with less features - like auto updating) then write a directive that would do almost the same thing but using single `template` element and modify the `document's` `DOM` only once.

If you want to have better understanding how this works, I suggest reading `ngRepeatDirective` https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

Comment: So is the answer to my question basically that with the `staticHtml` it's having to compile each repeated element, whereas with the `repeaterHtml` it's only having to compile the one `ng-repeat` element? To your first point, you are correct. It's only in the controller to make the fiddle easier to setup. This logic was in a directive link function in our real code.

Comment: Yes - you are performing a lot more operations on the `DOM` in your case than with `ng-repeat`.